# Regular expression date

Tags: javascript, regex

What's wrong with this regular expression? It won't work

```
var patt = /[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[1-9]{4}/;

if(patt.test(document.getElementById('date').value) == false){
    document.getElementById("errorTxt").innerHTML = "Error";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: "It won't work" is far too vague a description to be useful. Please state what you expect it to do vs actual behaviour.

Comment: Not sure as not JS wizard, but this looks like it will take dates such as 91/72/9123 as valid and 10/02/2001 as not valid (you don't even allow 0s in year). Have a look [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html) as to why regex might not be the best way out of this.

Comment: You don't care about date validation, correct :-?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the `/` in the middle.

```
var patt = /\d\d\/\d\d\/\d{4}/;
```

Also, why weren't you allowing 2012 to be a valid year?

Comment: This will match `91/72/9123`. Looks like OP accepted that :-?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `/` in middle of pattern. Make them `\/`.

Answer (score 0):

To use slashes within a regular expression, they must be escaped:

```
var patt = /[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[1-9]{4}/;
```

On a related note, you can use \d to represent any digit:

```
var patt = /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, how can you match year `2012` with `[1-9]{4}`, when there is `0` in `yyyy`?

Using regex `/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/` you can split date to numbers, but...

You should use [JavaScript Date Validation](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/144113/JavaScript-Date-Validation) instead.